# Wpf Styling Viewbox Path

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, fill

I have an user control like this.

```
Button
    Viewbox
        ContentPresenter
           Grid
               Path
```

I need to change `Button.Viewbox.Grid.Path.Fill` color.

Is there any way to do this?

My Style.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Style x:Key="PathStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Viewbox}">
    <!-- ?????????????????? -->
</Style>
```

I tried this

```
<Button>
    <Viewbox Width="18" Height="18" Style="{DynamicResource PathStyle}">
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource uriToUIElementConverter}, ConverterParameter=Images/New.xaml}"></ContentPresenter>
    </Viewbox>
</Button>
```

New.Xaml

```
<Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="newDocument" Fill="#FF000000" Stretch="Fill">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero" Figures="M43,30L50.75,30 43,22.25 43,30z M52,34L39,34 39,21 24,21 24,45 20,45 20,17 43.25,17 56,29.75 56,59 34,59 34,55 52,55 52,34z M28,38L33,38 33,46 41,46 41,51 33,51 33,59 28,59 28,51 20,51 20,46 28,46 28,38z M20,59L20,52 24,52 24,55 27,55 27,59 20,59z" />
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Grid>
```

Comment: and what have you tried.

Comment: I added now. I know a bit about styling.

Answer (score -1):

Uhm,

```
<Path Fill="Red" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="newDocument" Stretch="Fill">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero" Figures="M43,30L50.75,30 43,22.25 43,30z M52,34L39,34 39,21 24,21 24,45 20,45 20,17 43.25,17 56,29.75 56,59 34,59 34,55 52,55 52,34z M28,38L33,38 33,46 41,46 41,51 33,51 33,59 28,59 28,51 20,51 20,46 28,46 28,38z M20,59L20,52 24,52 24,55 27,55 27,59 20,59z" />
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

?

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I disagree, it's pretty self-explanatory.  The explanation is in the question, add a Fill color the the Path.